# Available text color classes in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a sign up page, by putting some text as the title at the navigation bar. I want to give those texts different colors. For this purpose I'm using a separate CSS file, but I want to do this using bootstrap's CSS file.

Can anybody list the available color classes in bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap uses one color `#333333` for text color.

Comment: it alone use only this?

Comment: But you can use different for different tag.

Comment: can u please explain this or place the link if possible

Answer (score 204, accepted):

The [bootstrap 3 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes) lists this under helper classes:
`Muted`, `Primary`, `Success`, `Info`, `Warning`, `Danger`.

The [bootstrap 4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/#color) lists this under utilities -> color, and has more options:
`primary`, `secondary`, `success`, `danger`, `warning`, `info`, `light`, `dark`, `muted`, `white`.

The [bootstrap 5 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/colors/) lists this under utilities -> color, and has even more options:
`primary`,`primary-emphasis`,`secondary`,`secondary-emphasis`,`success`,`success-emphasis`,`danger`,`danger-emphasis`,`warning`,`warning-emphasis`,`info`,`info-emphasis`,`light`,`light-emphasis`,`dark`,`dark-emphasis`,`body`,`body-emphasis`,`body-secondary`,`body-tertiary`,`black`,`white`,`black-50`,`white-50`.
Please be aware that some of these are deprecated and will be removed next release.

To access them one uses the `class` `text-[class-name]`

So, if I want the primary text color for example I would do something like this:

```
<p class="text-primary">This text is the primary color.</p>
```

This is not a huge number of choices, but it's some.

Comment: I would hesitate to say if you "want blue text". That class should be used when you're wanting to apply the primary color, which by default happens to be blue. But if `$primary` changes, then your formally blue text would also change.

If you want to make sure you always have blue text, you should set the text to whatever shade of blue you want it to be.

Answer (score 7):

The text at the navigation bar is normally colored by using one of the two following css classes in the `bootstrap.css` file.

Firstly, in case of using a default navigation bar (the gray one), the `.navbar-default` class will be used and the text is colored as [dark gray](http://www.color-hex.com/color/777777).

```
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #777;
}
```

The other is in case of using an inverse navigation bar (the black one), the text is colored as [gray60](http://www.color-hex.com/color/999999).

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-text {
  color: #999;
}
```

So, you can change its color as you wish. However, I would recommend you to use a separate css file to change it.

NOTE: you could also use the [customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize) provided by `Twitter Bootstrap`, in the `Navbar` section.

Answer (score 6):

You can use text classes:

```
.text-primary
.text-secondary
.text-success
.text-danger
.text-warning
.text-info
.text-light
.text-dark
.text-muted
.text-white
```

use text classes in any tag where needed.

```
<p class="text-primary">.text-primary</p>
<p class="text-secondary">.text-secondary</p>
<p class="text-success">.text-success</p>
<p class="text-danger">.text-danger</p>
<p class="text-warning">.text-warning</p>
<p class="text-info">.text-info</p>
<p class="text-light bg-dark">.text-light</p>
<p class="text-dark">.text-dark</p>
<p class="text-muted">.text-muted</p>
<p class="text-white bg-dark">.text-white</p>
```

You can add your own classes or modify above classes as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are few more classess in **Bootstrap 4** (added in recent versions) not mentioned in other answers.

`.text-black-50` and `.text-white-50` are 50% transparent.

```css
.text-body {
  color: #212529 !important;
}

.text-black-50 {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}

.text-white-50 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) !important;
}

/*DEMO*/
p{padding:.5rem}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<p class="text-body">.text-body</p>
<p class="text-black-50">.text-black-50</p>
<p class="text-white-50 bg-dark">.text-white-50</p>
```